# How to fix error in GitHub Actions caused by test task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to run test task in github actions by running `./gradlew build`. However, I get the following error.

I think it's an error that is caused by not able to read the test property which is located in `/src/test/resources/application.yml` maybe?

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test

GabojaitSpringApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

This is the folder structure.

```
|- src
|  |- main
|      |- java
|      |   |- ...
|      |- resources
|          |- application.yml
|- test
    |- java
    |   |- ...
    |- resources
        |- application.yml
```

This is the github workflows.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Grant execute permission for Gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build
        env:
          ...
          DB_DDL_TYPE: create
          DB_HOST: localhost
          DB_NAME: test_db
          DB_PASSWORD: rootpassword
          DB_PORT: 3306
          DB_USERNAME: root
          API_NAME: ${{ secrets.API_NAME }}
          ...
```

Finally, this is my empty Test class.

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I made a stupid mistake. It was a typo of one of the dependency injected.